# JPA saving 50k+ records taking more time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Below is my implementation for saving records into my table. when i try to save 2k records its saving fast but, if i try to save 20K records its taking more time or most of the time its not saving.

Please find my implementation below.

```
@Transactional
public ExcelClaimUpload createNewClaimUpload(ExcelClaimUpload claimUpload) {

   List<ExcelClaimUpload> excelClaimUploads = excelClaimUploadRepository.findByFilename(claimUpload.getFileName(),claimUpload.getUser().getId());
   for (ExcelClaimUpload excelClaimUpload : excelClaimUploads) {
   if (excelClaimUpload.getFileName().equals(claimUpload.getFileName())) ;
    {
      ExcelClaimUpload excelClaimUpload1 = excelClaimUploadRepository.findOne(excelClaimUpload.getId());
      excelClaimUpload1.setUploadLineItems(claimUpload.getUploadLineItems());
      claimUpload = excelClaimUploadRepository.save(excelClaimUpload1);  // taking more time when 50K records need to save in table.
    }
}
```

Please find my entity class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"uploadLineItems", "uploadTime"}, callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "excel_claim_upload")
@DiscriminatorValue("EXCEL")
public class ExcelClaimUpload extends ClaimUpload {

@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "upload_id")

private List<UploadLineItem> uploadLineItems = new ArrayList<UploadLineItem>();

}
```

Comment: Saving 20K records should take roughly ten times as long as saving 2K records.  Are you surprised that it takes longer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Actually its not saving into table and am getting `400` error code in UI. But this is not a case when am trying to load 2K records

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - If it will take roughly ten times as long as saving 2K records. so by the time i want to stop other thread to read the same table table. Can you suggest me how can i implement that?

Comment: Does your connection have auto-commit turned on?